# CMTime seconds output

Tags: objective-c, console, cmtime

This may seem ridiculous, but how can I output the seconds of CMTime to the console in Objective-C? I simply need the value divided by the timescale and then somehow see it in the console.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"seconds = %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime));
```

Comment: how about that case when CMTimeGetSeconds returns NaN?

Comment: My guess is the input is one of the [`CMTime` constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Time_Constants) (probably not `kCMTimeZero`).  Try using `CMTimeShow` to see what its fields are.

Answer (score 15):

Simple:

```
        NSLog(@"%lld", time.value/time.timescale);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to convert in `hh:mm:ss` format then you can use this

```
NSUInteger durationSeconds = (long)CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
NSUInteger hours = floor(dTotalSeconds / 3600);
NSUInteger minutes = floor(durationSeconds % 3600 / 60);
NSUInteger seconds = floor(durationSeconds % 3600 % 60);
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];
NSLog(@"Time|%@", time);
```

Answer (score 2):

All answers before this one do not handle NaN case:

**Swift 5:**

```
/// Convert CMTime to TimeInterval
///
/// - Parameter time: CMTime
/// - Returns: TimeInterval
func cmTimeToSeconds(_ time: CMTime) -> TimeInterval? {
    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
    if seconds.isNaN {
        return nil
    }
    return TimeInterval(seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print a `CMTime` to the console for debugging purposes use `CMTimeShow`:

**Objective-C**

```
CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(2.0, 60000); 
CMTimeShow(time);
```

**Swift**

```
var time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(2.0, 60000)
CMTimeShow(time)
```

It will print the `value`, `timescale` and calculate the `seconds`:

```
{120000/6000 = 2.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CMTime currentTime = audioPlayer.currentItem.currentTime;
 float videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime);
```